# VSFTPD cutted uploads

Tags: ssl, vsftpd

Installed VSFTPD v2.3.2 on a Wheezy.
When I try to put anything my ftp client (filezilla v3.5.3) it sends the file by parts of 229376 bytes interrupted by deconnexion/reconnexion untill the en of the upload. That's really boring...

Here is the vsftpd.conf :

```
listen=YES
use_localtime=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
connect_from_port_20=YES
ssl_enable=YES
ssl_tlsv1=YES
ssl_sslv2=NO
ssl_sslv3=NO
ssl_ciphers=HIGH
rsa_cert_file=/etc/vsftpd/ssl/vsftpd.pem
require_ssl_reuse=NO
debug_ssl=YES
vsftpd_log_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
syslog_enable=NO
xferlog_enable=YES
log_ftp_protocol=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=NO
local_enable=YES
local_umask=022
local_root=/var/www
user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/users
guest_enable=YES
guest_username=virtual
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd.chroot_list
ftpd_banner=welcome to our ftp service.
dirmessage_enable=YES
message_file=.message
dirlist_enable=YES
ls_recurse_enable=YES
secure_chroot_dir=/var/run/vsftpd
pam_service_name=vsftpd
tcp_wrappers=NO
```

Here is the vsftpd logs (1 cycle) :

```
Status: Connecting to ***.***.***.***:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 welcome to our ftp service.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER MyFTPLogin
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT now Private.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of /home/me/my_file.zip
Command:    CWD /MyServerFolder
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,84,146).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,44,227).
Command:    REST 117440512
Response:   350 Restart position accepted (117440512).
Command:    STOR my_file.zip
Response:   150 Ok to send data.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 229376 bytes in 20 seconds
```

And the filezilla logs (1 cycle too):

```
Status: Connecting to ***.***.***.***:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Response:   220 welcome to our ftp service.
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Command:    USER MyFTPLogin
Status: TLS/SSL connection established.
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ***********
Response:   230 Login successful.
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 Always in UTF8 mode.
Command:    PBSZ 0
Response:   200 PBSZ set to 0.
Command:    PROT P
Response:   200 PROT now Private.
Status: Connected
Status: Starting upload of /home/me/my_file.zip
Command:    CWD /MyServerFolder
Response:   250 Directory successfully changed.
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Switching to Binary mode.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,84,146).
Command:    LIST
Response:   150 Here comes the directory listing.
Response:   226 Directory send OK.
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (***,***,***,***,44,227).
Command:    REST 117440512
Response:   350 Restart position accepted (117440512).
Command:    STOR my_file.zip
Response:   150 Ok to send data.
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  File transfer failed after transferring 229376 bytes in 20 seconds
```

If I set my conf to be able to use unsecured connexions (force_local_data_ssl=NO and force_local_logins_ssl=NO), all works well.

Have you any explanation/solution to be able to use secured connexions correctly ?
Thanks a lot.

R.